# Modifying a query so that one field must contain a variable

Tags: php, mysql

The query below works well.  I would like to use it for search results now.  I would like to have it return the same results with this one modification:

The field `s.title` has the variable `$find` somewhere in it.  I. e., the field `s.title`. doesn't have to exactly equal `$find`, but it must have a word in it that equals `$find`.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT s.loginid, s.title, s.url, s.displayurl, s.datesubmitted, l.username,
  s.submissionid, COUNT(c.commentid) countComments, 
  GREATEST(s.datesubmitted, COALESCE(MAX(c.datecommented), s.datesubmitted)) AS most_recent
FROM submission s
INNER JOIN login l ON s.loginid = l.loginid
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment c ON s.submissionid = c.submissionid
GROUP BY s.submissionid
ORDER BY most_recent DESC
LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Comment: What do you mean specifically by a "word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sqlStr = "...WHERE s.title LIKE '%" . $find . "%'";
```

LIKE uses wildcards to match values

Comment: Note to OP - be careful: This could vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line before `GROUP BY` clause:

```
WHERE s.title LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($find) . "%'
```